# change in ion-content length causes scrollbar not being updated

Tags: html, ionic-framework, scroll

My Ionic1 app displays a list of items that can be collapsed/expanded, so the vertical length of the content can increase significantly when an element is expanded (the way I do it is through `ng-show` directives).

My issue is that when this happens, I cannot scroll down to see the new content. Actually, if I drag my finger from bottom to top, I can see the new content appear in the bottom, but as soon as I release my finger, some elasticity brings back the top of the content.

However, strangely enough, after a few seconds, the scrolling mechanics is updated correctly and I can scroll normally.

It looks like the Ionic framework takes some time to figure out that the content length has changed and needs some update in the scrolling mechanics... I would like to tell him immediately once it is needed. I tried to call $apply from the onClick call back of the Expand buttons, but I get an error saying I am already in a digest cycle.

Any clue to fix this please? Many thanks!

Comment: Please update some code snippet or codepen which will help to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid $apply approach because every $scope.$apply is rebind in the page. So you can follow the ionic scroll concept.
[ionic scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! this helped me fix the problem, by adding a call to `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()` whenever some item is collapsed/expanded.

You can check the issue with this fiddle: quickly expand groups 7/8/9 and try to scroll down:
http://jsfiddle.net/shengoo/6b0y3tar/